# How can I list all the import cycles in a Go project?

Tags: go

I'm refactoring a Go project where everything was in a single module, splitting out sub packages. Having done that, there are many import cycles. In order for the project to compile again, I have to eliminate them. However, after doing a change that I think has eliminated a cycle, the import cycle count seems to remain the same. I count the cycles with this command:

```sh
go build 2>&1 | grep package | wc -l
```

It keeps reporting 6 even after I do work that seems like it should have removed a cycle, and even after I no longer see the cycle I removed in the list. It makes me wonder if it's only reporting a subset of the issues.

I also tried

```sh
go build -gcflags="-e" 2>&1 | grep package | wc -l
```

as suggested at https://menno.io/posts/showing-all-go-compiler-errors/, but it gave the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I list all the import cycles in a Go project?

You can try with

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' <import-path>
```

Will show import dependencies for package at  - or in current directory if  is left empty. Alternatively

```
go list -f '{{join .DepsErrors "\n"}}' <import-path>
```

hopefully shows some useful information in your case.

Also, there's godepgraph: https://github.com/kisielk/godepgraph

```
go get github.com/kisielk/godepgraph
```

Basic usage

```
godepgraph -s path/to/my/package
```

[image]